# Поменять местами текст до символа и после

Tags: notepad++

Например,строка:"жирная:точка",нужно преобразовать все таким образом,чтобы вышло "точка:жирная".В данном,символом выступает двоеточие.

Answer (score 3):

Открываем файл в `Notepad++`
Жмем `CTRL+F`
Выбираем режим поиска: `Регулярные выражения`

В поле `Найти:` пишем: `(\w+):(\w+)`
В поле `Заменить на:` пишем: `\2:\1`